Displacement Map deformes the Mesh wierd. Any idea what causes the problem?
As you can see I created a displacement map and imported it into blender. This is the important part of my map, that causes wierd deforming.


on the second image you can see the result of the deforming. I just have a simple node setup for that. I thought maybe its the mesh density but I subdevided it multiple times and the "error" was still there. Any ideas?
UPDATE:
we fidgert out, that maybe the density of the mesh is to low to displace it correctly. So here is an image of the object without applied subdivisions:

I marked the spot where I want to create the engraving and as you can see, the rims has this spot 5 times and I want to engrave all of them different. Now comes the problem, how should I subd the mesh without crashing blender or deforming the subd with loopcuts? I applied the modifier once with almost 8.000.000 verts as you can see in the following image:

This works much better but it is still to less density on the importanat spots. Do you have an idea how to fix it? maybe like Subd it once with smaller steps and make loopcuts by hand?

That is a Normal Map, not displacement

Oh, thanks. Where is the difference, I thought you are able to use a normal map for that too. And I mean even if it is a normal map it doesn`t explain why it is shows errors.

A displacement map is scalar value usually from 0 to 1 (greyscale image) that will tell how much each vertex must be displaced along its face normals. It can be interpreted as a normal map, but here you have a normal map. A normal map is a 3D map where the red, green and blue channels are used to display the relative displacement in 3D space, it fakes geometry by telling the renderer to shade the surface differently depending on the values of the normal map sampled at each pixel. It must be treated through a normal map node, and the color space but me set to non-color.

Polygon density is NOT the problem. DO NOT SUBDIVIDE THE MESH!

I don’t think this has to do with the displacement map itself, but the mapping of the displacement map onto the surface. That is, the UV texture coordinates. Have a look at the UV map of the mesh in those locations, and see if it looks deformed significantly from the mesh shape. Note that if the mesh is made of very long, thin triangles, these problems may not be as easy to notice. A mesh should be as close to a grid as possible generally.
If the UV map seems to match the mesh well (I.e. it is not heavily deformed), you may need to subdivide it a little as the texture stretching in Blender is not very smart. I doubt that’s the issue though, since the problem seems very localized.

You are right, I checked everything and the uvs are good, but I think I need even  more density. But its not that easy. I dont now how I should give it more subd without crashing blender. I will edit the post so you can see the object better and maybe you have an idea how I could give it only in the needed areas more density.

STOP! You didn’t mention that this was a 3D scan, of course the UVs are going to be garbage. That is already WAY too many vertices.

Thanks for your idea. No it is not a 3d scan. I played around with some ideas and found a solution. On the image its subdivided 8 times and yes it was to much verts. I went back to my low poly mesh and seperated the part that needs the displacement. Then I subdivided only these and it worked perfectly. The performance is still good because the rest is still the low poly version without playing modifier. I will update the post soon... maybe then its more understandable

Note, don’t edit your answer into the original question, post it as an answer itself. I’m glad you found a solution, though I still feel like something else in your workflow was off maybe; You might encounter this problem again if you don’t fix that.
